# MS Access Update with addition

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, updates, addition

I'm working with MS Access and would like to how to update the data correctly..here is the code i use on my button click event with no luck

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM ItemTemp WHERE ITEM='" + txtItemname.Text + "'", GetConnection());
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

//check if this item exist on the table ItemTemp
if (reader.HasRows == true)
{
    // item exists, do below action
    OleDbCommand cmde = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE ItemTemp SET QUANTITY=QUANTITY + @QUANTITY, PRICE=PRICE + @PRICE WHERE ITEM='" + txtItemname.Text + "'", GetConnection());
    cmde.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTITY", txtItemquantity.Value); //numericupdown control
    cmde.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRICE", txtItemprice.Text); //textbox control
    cmde.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

data on database BEFORE updating:

```
ID    |    ITEM    |    QUANTITY    |    PRICE
1     |    ITEM1   |        1       |    400
```

data on database AFTER updating:

```
ID    |    ITEM    |    QUANTITY    |    PRICE
1     |    ITEM1   |       11       |    400400
```

data on database which i want it to be AFTER updating:

```
ID    |    ITEM    |    QUANTITY    |    PRICE
1     |    ITEM1   |        2       |    800
```

i do believe my command is correct if not my bad..there's no other than this code on my button click event. any ideas?

Comment: It seems that your Quantity and Price column are of Text type. Could you confirm this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: FYI, your two `OleDbCommand` and your `OleDbDataReader` need to be in `using` blocks.

Comment: @Steve, not sure about numericupdown since its only accept number, and yes on price

Comment: No, I am talking about the columns in the database table. Look in MS Access and check in the table structure the datatype. It should be numeric (Long Integer, Float, decimal) not text.

Comment: You are adding strings basically concat them `"400" + "400" does not equal 800` it equals `"400400"` Price should be of type Currency or Double if you are working with decimal values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should be sure that the database fields Quantity and Price are oo numeric type. If they are Text then your query concatenate the string values passed as parameters with the string present  in the database column.

Second, when you pass the parameters with AddWithValue the framework infers the datatype for you looking at the datatype of the passed value. In your case you pass a string and and the database engine sees a string that will be concatenated to the existing value. You need to convert before passing to an appropriate datatype

Finally, use allways parametrized query for every thing you pass to the database engine, especially if the value passed comes from an input textbox.

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM ItemTemp WHERE ITEM=@item", GetConnection());
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", txtItemName.Text);
 OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 //check if this item exist on the table ItemTemp
 if (reader.HasRows == true)
 {
     OleDbCommand cmde = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE ItemTemp SET QUANTITY=QUANTITY + @QUANTITY," + 
     "PRICE=PRICE + @PRICE WHERE ITEM=@item, GetConnection());
     cmde.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTITY", Convert.ToInt32(txtItemquantity.Value)); 
     cmde.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRICE", Convert.ToDecimal(txtItemprice.Text)); 
     cmde.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", txtItemName.Text);
     cmde.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: you were just a bit minute late lol..i just notice your code look clean, anyway there are an error on this area, Parameters.AddWithValue("@iten", txtItemName.Text);, it need to be @item, hehe..thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

ok, its seem to be done now. i just change

```
cmde.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTITY", txtItemquantity.Value); //numericupdown control
cmde.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRICE", txtItemprice.Text); //textbox control
```

to this

```
cmde.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTITY", Convert.ToInt32(txtItemquantity.Value));
cmde.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRICE", Convert.ToInt32(txtItemprice.Text));
```